# Ping command not working in all android devices

Tags: android

I am using following code to execute ping command in android.
Process proc = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 -s 1024 8.8.8.8");
Problem is that i have tested with many devices but in some devices works fine but in some devices it does not work. So, Please let me know if you guys have any solution that ping command work in all devices. I have been searching for 5 days but did not find and solutions.

Comment: You can't rely on any command being there for exec.  If it isn't part of the official API, it isn't reliable.

Comment: Is there other way to execute ping command in android ?